# ASPX If statement not loading my content

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I have something like this:

```
<%If (Request.Url.ToString = "default.aspx") Then %>
        <li><a href="url">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="url">Link</a></li>
    <%ElseIf (Request.Url.ToString = "anotherdefault.aspx") Then %>
        <li><a href="url">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="url">Link</a></li>
```

But for some odd reason it isn't bringing up the links for that certain URL. But when I put a breakpoint on my vb page it works. Think that the IF statement is causing a css problem?

Comment: The `If` statement definitely shouldn't be causing a CSS problem, unless your web server isn't processing the code (which would be a much bigger problem), since the VB code isn't rendered on the client.  Is the `Url` ever _just_ the page name like this?  Try just adding `<%= Request.Url.ToString %>` on the page and see what it outputs.

Comment: The url for the string is the correct one I put in as the =. The url of course is the full path and not the absolute path.  It works if I get rid of the if statement and just have a group of links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "=" is case sensitive.  If you're testing by typing the URL into the browser, you might not be testing exactly what is coming from the app.  Try using `Request.Url.ToString.ToLower() = "default.aspx"`

Comment: Ok, you win haha. I thought I checked that but I guess not. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an EndIf. If not try something else for the conditional, like just true or false. I would definitely say that it is no a css problem. The inline code is evaluated before css ever sees the doc.